# One Hot Encoding (mapping values issue)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, encoding, multilabel-classification

I am working on a multilabel text classification.
I am doing one hot encoding for my training and testing labels such that at first I created a list which contains all labels i.e 8921 unique labels then I am doing one-hot encoding as with the help of a list as follows:
**note:** for following code:
b is my list of 8921 labels
and df['LABELS'] look like as follows:

```
b=['865.09','482.1','860.4','31.29', ......, '76.74', '76.92', '79.32']

LABELS
[532.40,493.20,V45.81,412,401.9,44.43]
[211.3,427.31,578.9,560.1,496,584.9,428.0,276.5]
[440.22, 492.8, 401.9, 714.0, 39.29, 88.48]
```

**my code:**

```
for label in b:
   df[label]=np.where((df['LABELS'])==label,1,0)
df[['LABELS']+b].head()
```

**Output that i get:**

```
   LABELS    038.9   785.59  584.9   427.5   410.71   .....     428.0    682.6   425.4  
0  [038.9,     0       0      0       0        0                   0       0       0       
   493.20,    
   V45.81,   
   682.6, 
   401.9, 
   44.43]

1  [472.5,      0       0       0      0        0      .....        0        0       0        
   428.0,  
   578.9, 
   560.1, 
   496, 
   584.9]
```

**Desired output**

```
   LABELS    038.9   785.59  584.9   427.5   410.71   .....     428.0    682.6   425.4  
0  [038.9,     1       0      0       0        0                   0       1       0       
   493.20,    
   V45.81,   
   682.6, 
   401.9, 
   44.43]

1  [472.5,      0       0       1      1        0      .....        1        0       0        
   428.0,  
   578.9, 
   560.1, 
   496, 
   584.9]
```

kindly help where i am doing mistake while iterating my df['LABEL'] values.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `df['LABELS']` is a series and contains a list in each row. So `np.where` probably checks this list with a single label. For example it checks if `[532.40,493.20,V45.81,412,401.9,44.43] == '865.09'` which obviously returns `False`.

Apart from that, the labels in `b` are strings whereas the labels in `df['LABELS']`
don't seem to be. This will also result in `False` as `'865.09' == 865.09` are not the same.

Comment: You are right. As for as data type is concerned I will change and keep same for b and df['LABELS']. But how can I change my code so that np.where can iterate my list elements individually?

Comment: Try using the ```in``` operator to test membership.

Comment: can you kindly share my updated code above here with in operator as you are suggesting. It will be easy for me to understand